# insert textfield value into a collection in struts2

Tags: struts2

I have this bean class

```
  Class Address {
    private String addressId;
    private Set<Location> setOfLocations;

    // more attributes


   //getters and setters

 }

 Class Location{
     private Long   locationId;
     private String locationName
     private String nearestHospital;

     //getters and setters
 }
```

in the jsp I have a textField controls for the Address class members, and also for Location class members one for locationName and nearestHospital.

the Address class members map normally because the model driven interface map them to their respective fields. the problem is how i can map the location textFields to a location object inside Set member of the Address class

Comment: I updated my answer following your comment. Please let me know if i am now answering your question and consider updating your question with the clarification your comment provided.

Comment: your modified answer did not solve my problem.
I know that i can do this in the execute() method, what i want is unleash the power of struts2, the Model driven interface has a great power in storing the fields of jsp from into the bean, without any coding in the execute() method. i want also to add an element to the collection of Location inside the Address bean also using the model driven interface.
how can write the name of the textfields in the JSP sothat they map implicitly to the collection of Location inside the Address bean

Comment: you seem to have a lot of requirements that you didn't state up front.  why should i waste anymore of my time trying to answer your question when you cant take the time to state the question correctly up front?

Comment: i said everything in my question, it's not my problem if you could not understand what i wanted.
i said " the Address class members map normally because the model driven interface map them to their respective fields. the problem is how i can map the location textFields to a location object inside Set member of the Address class "
i did not say how to display them on jsp, nevertheless i did not thumb down your answer.
i mentioned the model driven in the question, next time read the question carefully before you answer.

Comment: don't just ignore Model driven mapping in the question just to answers and increase your points.
if answering questions is wasting of your time. then please don't answer question anymore. the stackOverFlow members do not like to waste your precious time

Comment: please, feel free to thumb me down brother.  it's no sweat off my back if you don't learn to ask questions in a way that gets people to answer them.

Comment: the question was clear, therefore your solution is easy and if others understood the question as you did then you will find 3 or 4 other answers, but none answered because they do not know the answer, it's ok that they don't know the answer.
i think there is no way of doing what i want.
please read the question next time and you need clarification then i can provide. 
please next time read your comments before you post them, yours was not polite

Comment: Nah, most Struts2 questions on here only get one or two answers.  Your question did not mention that you wanted to use type conversion or that you required a strict use of `ModelDriven`.  You did not say that you already knew one way to do it but that you were looking for a more elegant solution.  Those are the things that should be included up front if they are important to you.  You didn't even explicitly state that you wished to add an item to the set rather the edit an existing item.

Comment: You seem to think that these things are obvious, but as someone who has likely read many more questions on here than you have read, I think that you might be surprised how inexperienced most askers are and therefore how little an answerer can rightly assume the asker to already know and understand about the framework.

Comment: well i did not say i know one whay to doit but isaid i wanted to be done using modelDriven, beside i said literally "the problem is how i can map the location textFields to a location object inside Set member of the Address class"
anyhow, i thank you for your effort to help me.
it seems that there is no way to do it using modelDriven.

regards

Answer (score 0):

#### Add new item to collection

Using type conversion and a `list` instead of a `set`, this will work to add a new item to the list:

```
<s:textfield name="locations[%{locations.size()}].locationName"/>
```

If you want to use a set, then I don't know how to achieve what you want without spending some time digging, but you will want to start [here](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/type-conversion.html#TypeConversion-CollectionandMapSupport).

---

#### Display and edit existing collection items

On the other hand, if you were to want to be able to display and edit an existing collection, then this should work if you use a `list` instead of a `collection`:

```
<s:iterator var="listItem" value="yourList" status="listStatus">
   <s:set name="paramName">yourList[${ listStatus.index }].someField</s:set>
   <s:textfield name="%{#paramName}" value="%{#listItem.someField}"/>
</s:iterator>
```

Here, your model would have a list called `yourList`.  The items in yourList contain a field called `someField`.  We are able to set the value onto the fields by setting the request parameter name to be in the form `yourList[2].someField` so that `OGNL` will evaluate this and set the parameter value onto the someField field of item 2 of yourList.

Using your classes as you show them above but with changing the locations to a list, we would have:

```
<s:iterator var="location" value="listOfLocations" status="locationStatus">
   <s:set name="paramName">listOfLocations[${ locationStatus.index }]</s:set>
   <s:hidden name="%{#paramName}.locationId" value="%{#location.locationId}"/>
   <s:textfield name="%{#paramName}.locationName" value="%{#location.locationName}"/>
   <s:textfield name="%{#paramName}.nearestHospital" value="%{#location.nearestHospital}"/>
</s:iterator>
```

Or, if you are using `JSTL`, this will do the same:

```
<c:forEach var="location" items="${ listOfLocations }" varStatus="locationStatus">
   <s:set name="paramName">listOfLocations[${ locationStatus.index }]</s:set>
   <s:hidden name="%{#paramName}.locationId" value="%{#location.locationId}"/>
   <s:textfield name="%{#paramName}.locationName" value="%{#location.locationName}"/>
   <s:textfield name="%{#paramName}.nearestHospital" value="%{#location.nearestHospital}"/>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: you solution apply if i have a none empty list and you want to generate textFields for every element in the list.
but my case is that i have jsp that has fields only 3 fields for locationsId, LocationName and nearstHospital. when i submit the form thier values should be stored in the collection, then the same jsp will show up again to anter another location.
i don't want to draw textFields depending on how much Location objects i have in the collection.
beside that the first time i reach to this page the collection will be empty,and it should be filled by one object each time i submit the form